# HTML CSS Change Color of SELECT ARROW

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to change the color of the SELECT arrow to blue.

Is there a simple way to do this?

[image: SELECT BOX]

Comment: Can you post the CSS and the HTML code which is responsible for this dropdown to appear.

Comment: select { color: transparent; -webkit-text-fill-color: black; }

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```css
.select_box{
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.select_box:after{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 5px;
  content: "";
  z-index: 98;
 }
.select_box select{
  width: 220px;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_box">
 <select>
   <option>Test This Select</option>
   <option>Test This Select</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also recommend `pointer-events: none` for `select_box:after` since otherwise the dropdown will not open when you exactly click on the arrow. :-)

Comment: It's helpful to explain the core function of the code you have added here. Anyone reading this has to look through in depth to extract the minimum necessary to achieve the stated objective.

Answer (score 6):

try this code segment:

```css
.customerStyle select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 35px;
}

.customerStyle {
   background: url("images/arrow.png") no-repeat right #ffffff;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   width: 150px;
   height: 35px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class="customerStyle">
   <select class="selectCustomer">
       <option value="Jone">Jone</option>
       <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Add blue color arrow image for `"images/arrow.png"`.