# change dropdown arrow color with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change the arrow color in this to blue

[image]
I have this code for dropdown menu.I tried this solution but its not working

[HTML CSS Change Color of SELECT ARROW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870246/html-css-change-color-of-select-arrow/38870462)

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:right;margin-right:0px">
                <label for="priority">Task priority</label><br>
                <select class="form-control" style="width:380px">
                <option value="urgent" selected="selected">Urgent</option>
                <option value="important">important</option>
                <option value="later">Later</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div>
```

CSS
.

```
form-control{
       border:0 !important;
       outline:none !important;
       color:black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
        /* padding:20px !important; */
        height: 43px !important;
        border-radius:4px !important;  
    }
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't match any of the code from the linked question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58290685/edit) to include the actual code you're using, including the CSS code.

Comment: edited with the corresponding CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the default HTML select boxes. These are usually styled by the browser. You can change little style settings like you did. Looks like you are using a library like bootstrap, which predefine a style for them.

Back to the question: you can't really change that color. You could try to hide these default elements with

> appearance: none;
>   
> -moz-appearance: none;
>     -webkit-appearance: none;

and make a custom css styling.

```
.selectorDiv
{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.selectorDiv::before
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;

  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;

  margin-left: auto;

  content: "";
  z-index:5;

  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;

  border-left: 10px solid green;  

  pointer-events:none;

}
```

Edit: including jfiddle with own styling https://jsfiddle.net/3ngzk1vp/1/

Comment: the question is which are these elements?

Comment: Adding these css to your select element will hide the arrow. Now you can try adding your own triangle. I would try placing it with absolute positioning.

Comment: .form-control::after{
    appearance: none;
   } tried that but its still visible

Comment: See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ngzk1vp/

Comment: Does the jsfiddle helps you? Make sure to add  pointer-events:none; to the ::before element, so it opens the option even if you click on the triangle.