# How to change html select arrow color?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, dropdown

How to change the color of the dropdown arrow? (Same style arrow)

```css
#cars{
width:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply change the color. Remove the default one and add your custom SVG/image in the background.
In below CSS, replace background URL with your custom SVG/image

```
select{
     background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 100% 50%;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can depend on the Browser you are viewing it in, but usually you only need to set the `color` attribute to your desired color.

```css
#cars{
  width:150px;
  color: red; // add this line
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But i want just to change color of the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

To start with the conclusion, you can't change. So most UI libraries create containers that wrap around Select Box, and use virtual selectors to customize arrows.
The example below might help.

[HTML CSS Change Color of SELECT ARROW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870246/html-css-change-color-of-select-arrow)